# Dirac bra-ket and basis notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation

I will post a image elucidating what is my doubt. I think it is more interesting to post it than to just write the equations used in the text because maybe I am losing something in the lecture.

See the equation 1.3.5, why it is written in this way? That is, following the previous equations, shouldn't be $\left \langle V \right \rangle = \sum_{i}\left \langle i|V\right \rangle|i\rangle$ ?

Comment: In the future, please do not post images or text and/or math. Please type the text and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter, because $\langle j|V\rangle$ is just a number.  It's written that way to reflect the fact that $\sum_i |i\rangle\langle i|$ is the identity operator.  Acting with it on $|V\rangle$ from the left then gives an expansion of $|V\rangle$ in the basis $|i\rangle$.